# MS Access - context menu - get root control

Tags: ms-access, callback, vba, contextmenu

I have a form where user can preview differents docs associated with an invoice (PO, invoice, transportation instructions...). To simplify I will call them doc#1, doc#2, doc#3. Each document is saved on specific directory.

On the invoice form, there are 3 buttons (button_doc1, button_doc2, button_doc#3)

I want the following behaviour :

- on left-click, user is able to preview the document (report open on right click event)
- on right-click, context-menu appears to offer opening directory which contains the doc.

So I try with a context menu defined as follow :

```
Sub CreateFormShortcutMenu_OpenReportDir()
   Dim cmbRightClick As Office.CommandBar
   Dim cmbControl As Office.CommandBarControl

   ' Create the shortcut menu.

   Set cmbRightClick = CommandBars.Add("cmdShortCutMenu_FormOpenReportDir", msoBarPopup, False, True)

   With cmbRightClick
            ' Add the DeleteRecord command.
            Set cmbControl = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton, , , , True)
       With cmbControl
          .BeginGroup = True
          .Caption = "Open dir"
          .OnAction = "=CallbackOpenDocDir()"
          .FaceId = 106
      End With

   End With

   Set cmbControl = Nothing
   Set cmbRightClick = Nothing

   End Sub
```

I wonder if it is possible to use the same context menu on the 3 buttons (to avoid redundant code) ? How can I get the button (name or ref) that triggered the callback.

```
Public Function CallbackOpenDocDir()
  dim strDocName as string 

  'code to get the button / doc name

  select case strDocName
      case "Doc#1"
          openFileExplorer doc1Dir
      case "Doc#2"
          openFileExplorer doc2Dir
      case "Doc#3"
          openFileExplorer doc3Dir
  end select

End Function
```

Thanks for you ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this form's code to determine clicked button name:

```
Me.ActiveControl.Name
```

or call from anywhere

```
Screen.ActiveControl.Name
```